Create a unskippable overlay in android
I want to create an unskippable screen that is forced to show to the user at a particular time or when the app desired too, under the acknowledgment of the user (it is an attempt to create a self-controlling overlay for the user to break his habits of reaching apps and websites unconsciously. The user will allow the actions implemented by the app)
Due to constraints in android, I'm failing to get it working. I want to create an overlay that can be applied at any time, survive (or prevent) the app being killed by the android, and forcing the user to go through it, unable to ignore it.
Is there any way I can achieve this in android?
I see deprecations  like  by android that's not allowing to provide rigid restrictions on user action.

What i understood is, you don't want the user to kill the app unless it's allowed to do so.
AFAIK, you cannot do this in any user-friendly OS. As this is the far most important feature that OS gives. Let the user decide what they intend to do.
Kindly elaborate your question further.
